# Git Bash npm package commands not found

Tags: bash, git, npm

I have recently installed Vue-cli globally via npm on Git Bash. However, when I run `vue`, I get `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found`. I'm not an expert at bash, but I'm pretty sure that the PATH isn't set up correctly. But if I run `env|grep PATH` I can see `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\npm` in my path.

However if I run `vue` on my basic cmd, it works as intended. Is there something that my git bash is missing? Also, if I run `npm config get prefix` I get `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

Note that I used Vue as an example. I get the same error when running `create-react-app`.

I have the latest version of git bash (2.28.0) and on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal emulator installed by git is named Mintty. To run npm with Mintty, you need to add the path to an environment variable.

Add the following line to your ~.bash_profile file. If it does not exist, create it
When Mintty starts up it will read .bash_profile. You should now be able to run npm
These other questions might be helpful also.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables

Comment: sorry, I'm not too familiar with terminal. What line do I add to my .bash_profile?

Comment: Also, I cannot save bash_profile (editing on vim). It says cannot open file for writing. Do I have to chmod it or something?

Comment: You should absolutely have the privileges to save a file in your home directory. Sounds like maybe you are trying to save it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the place you installed NodeJs is your Windows PATH environment variable.  This should be easy to look up via a web search
2. Bring up Git Bash
3. enter the command "cd" without quotes
4. enter: notepad .bash_profile
5. add this line at the bottom of the file:

   export Path="YourNodeJSDirectory:$PATH"
6. Cloe Git Bash and then restart it